# Laravel Undefined Variable: donor ErrorException in d03bd104494df21919e458a02c3243e2b323db06.php line 3:

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a controller which mainly has two functions. First function adds the user to the database and sends an email (receipt.blade.php) to the user.The second function allows the user to get all the receipts for a particular email that a user enters.

Right now, if I directly go to the page where the user can enter the email and get all receipts, its working fine. But, if I try to do it through the process of adding a new user I get the error described in the title after I click submit to adding the user. However, it has added the user to the database, but shows the error because its sending the email which is the receipt.blade.php and has the undefined variable. My controller has these:

```
use App\Donor;
use App\Video;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

The first Function is:

```
public function thankyoupage(Request $data, Mailer $mailer){
$donor = Donor::create([
            'first_name'=> $data->first_name,
            'last_name' => $data->last_name,
            'email' => $data->email,
            'video_count' => $video_count,
            'amount_donated' => $data->amount_donated,
});

$mailer
            ->to($data->input('email'))
            ->send(new \App\Mail\MyMail(($data->input('first_name')),($data->input('last_name')),
                ($data->input('amount_donated'))));

return redirect()->action('PagesController@thank1');
    }
```

My mailing file(mailable) is:

```
class MyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $first_name, $last_name, $amount_donated;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($first_name,$last_name,$amount_donated)
    {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;
        $this->last_name = $last_name;
        $this->amount_donated = $amount_donated;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('myemailid12341@gmail.com')
            ->view('emails.receipt');
    }
}
```

The second function is:

```
public function getUserReceipts(Request $data){
    $email = $data->email;

    $donor = Donor::where('email', $email)->get(); 

   return view('emails.receipt')->with(compact('donor'));
}
```

The receipt file simply contains:

```
@foreach($donor as $value)
    {{ $value->first_name }}
    {{ $value->last_name }}
    {{ $value->amount_donated }}
@endforeach
```

> The error I'm getting seems to be because donor in the receipt file is
>   undefined and I'm not sure how to fix it as it was passed with compact
>   in the second function.

Would really appreciate the help.

Comment: You've created `$donor` with `Donor::create([` but ended with `}]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your last question i can see the problem. The issue is that you're reusing the same view which takes two different set of data. When used with the method `getUserReceipts`, it generates receipts for multiple donors. But when you send the mail you're using the view as the mail content. In that case you need to use the properites set in the mailable class. The ideal case would be to create a new view for sending a single email receipt and handle it like so.

Change your mailable class to this. With this you can use all the properties of the donor in your view.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Donor;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class MyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $donor;

    public function __construct(Donor $donor)
    {
        $this->donor = $donor;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('myemailid12341@gmail.com')
            ->view('emails.singlereceipt');
    }
}
```

Change the way you send the email to

```
\Mail::to($data->input('email'))->send(new \App\Mail\MyMail($donor));
```

Create a new view `singlereceipt.blade.php` and use the following code instead.

```
{{ $donor->first_name }}
{{ $donor->last_name }}
{{ $donor->amount_donated }}
```

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested but received this error: **"Argument 1 passed to App\Mail\MyMail::__construct() must be an instance of App\Mail\Donor, instance of App\Donor given, called in C:\Users\Dell\final\app\Http\Controllers\PagesController.php on line 116 and defined"**. Line 116 is the \Mail::to($data......) line. Any ideas?

Comment: @AJth add `use App\Donor;` on the top like i have or change the constructor argument from `Donor $donor` to `\App\Donor $donor`

Comment: I hadn't seen your post before, so I just changed my mailer to as it was before and passed the singlereceipt.blade instead of receipt.blade in the build function, so now its working fine. And yes, I was missing the use App\Donor, so I'm sure what you just said would work as well. But since its working anyways I guess I don't have to do anything more, right?Or do you think it might cause any problems..I don't have any more significant functions to implement. Also, thanks for your help

Comment: @AJth having the mail moved to a separate class like i've showed you is good practise. In the end it comes to preferences. Choose whichever you feel is better for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in sending data to view. If you send data using `with()` function than syntax should be:

```
return view('emails.receipt')->with('donor', $donor);
```

See [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views)